# How to set background color of an image, but within the border?

Tags: android, graphics

**My goal** is to display a circular image, and allow the user to set its `foreground` and `background` colors respectively, for example:

[image: desired output]

**My attempt** was to create an image asset with transparent background, then use `ImageView::setColorFilter` to change its foreground, and use `ImageView::setBackgroundColor` to set its background. The image asset looks like this:

[image: my attempt]

**My problem** is that pixels outside of what we humans call 'border' are also transparent, so the result looks like this:

[image: undesired result]

How do people usually deal with this issue? Although I was doing Android development, but any ideas or code snippets in any language are appreciated!

Comment: Depending on the platform and the resources I would have created a mask that specifies the area of the image that's not supposed to be affected. And then apply it by having that image above the original one, like a stencil. It would br the same as having the area outside the border as not transparent, but I assume that would affect the `setColorFilter` function.

Answer (score 0):

at the first, you must create a new drawable file and write below code for creating the circle with yellow color with blue border:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="oval">

     <solid android:color="#cab816" />


     <size android:width="50dp"
      android:height="50dp"/>

     <stroke android:width="2dp"
      android:color="@color/darkBlue"/>
     </shape>
```

and now you must set this drawable to the background of your imageview and set your image with src.

if your image covered all of this circle, use padding for decrease image size.

Comment: if your image has a border you must erase <stork> tag.